# neo4j Cypher iteratively creating relationships in optimal way

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am making a social media app where users can invite lists of other users to "events." To write a Cypher query to invite each user on a list to an event--i.e. to create an `INVITED` relationship between each user and an event node, what is the best approach?

Should I iteratively create relationships with a single Cypher transaction? I'm not sure what that would look like. Alternatively, I could loop through each user in my Node.js backend and write a transaction creating a single `INVITED` relationship for each user on the list. My guess is that the latter approach is not optimal, as I would need to `MATCH` the same event for each transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you have access the something that identifies the users on your Node.js backend already when starting the query, such as as an `id` property. If so then the query becomes

```
MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.id IN $user_ids
MATCH (event:Event) WHERE event.id = $event_id
CREATE (user)-[:INVITED_TO]->(event)
```

This query will hit the db once for fetching the event and once for each member of the user ID's.

You can then pass the parameters `user_ids` and `event_id` when executing the query from Node.js.

Comment: Yes, I'll have a list of user ids. I didn't know the `IN` keyword existed in Cypher

Comment: As a sidenote, is `MATCH (event:Event) WHERE event.id = $event_id` more efficient than `MATCH (event:Event {id: $event_ID})`?

Comment: As far as I know it is exactly the same. If you need a good resource for what you can do in Cypher then I can recommend their refcards, they have pretty much everything you'll need in the core language: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/3.5/

Answer (score 2):

You can use lists in cypher and combined with `UNWIND`, you can achieve this with a single statement,

```
WITH ["user1","user2", "user3"] as users 
UNWIND users as user
MATCH (u:User {id: user})
MATCH (e:Event {id: 'event1'}) 
CREATE (u)-[:INVITED]->(e)
```